# How to Show Highscores with Username and save it locally for the leadboard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, local-datastore

I'm trying to show high scores of my game w.r.t their users so that one with highest score stays on top.
I already made an activity where it ask user for their desire username.And it should save the progress for the next time.

Comment: This could be done dozens of ways, and depends upon the circumstance and your goal.

Comment: How please tell me?

Comment: Again it depends upon your goal and circumstance.  And, their are a lot of ways it could be done.

Comment: I just want to show the score with username.how can it be done?

Comment: I got that, again this can be done many different ways and how I would explain it would depend upon your experience.  Maybe start here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage